# How to solve this job scheduling programming problem?

Tags: algorithms, dynamic-programming

I am trying to solve this question. The question is a variation of job scheduling. There are n processes given to you with their execution time `Ti` and individual deadlines `Di`. A process can be executed anytime before its deadline. A process can not be executed after its deadline is over. So, you have to find the maximum number of processes that can be executed. Given that `n <= 1000` and `Ti & Di <= 1,000,000` For example:

```
Ti Di
3  4
4  8
11 23
```

**Answer = 3**

I tried to solve this question using branch & bound mechanism. I first sort the processes on the basis of deadline. Then like `0/1 knapsack`, I recursively took 2 cases. One is to take current process and other one is to discard this process. But the complexity of this approach is **2^n** and it gave me TLE. Please suggest a better approach for this problem.

Comment: what are your approaches?

Comment: Please give the reference to the original problem.

Answer (score 1):

I assume your question is "how many jobs can you achieve on time ?". The idea to use something like 0/1 knapsack is good. There is actually a DP resolution of 0/1 knapsack much more efficient than "recursively select or discard each item".

Let's call $t_{max} = max(D[i])$, the end horizon of your problem.

Create a vector $A$ of size $t_{max}$, $A_i[t]$ stands for the number of achieved jobs at time $t$ after considering all jobs until $i^{th}$ one. Initially, $A_0$ is filled with 0.

Then you loop on jobs, to build $A_i$ from $A_{i-1}$:

```
for t from D[i] to T[i] by -1:
    A[t] = max(A[t], A[t-T[i]]+1)
```

Time complexity is $O(Nt_{max})$.

Comment: Your approach is good but, I'm getting TLE. Since, number of test cases = 70

Comment: @Abhay_Agarwal  What are you talking about ? TLE ?

Comment: Time Limit Exceed

Comment: @Abhay_Agarwal  Will you give the reference to the problem ?